# recursive call in AWS AppSync dynamodb resolver

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I want to write a recursive call using dynamodb-resolver. Let say whenever i hit a **[dynamodb limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-api)**

1. DynamoDB Batch operations - unprocessed key
2. query limit of1 mb with nexttoken
3. scan limit of 1 mb with nexttoken

I should be able to make a recursive call, whenever the "context.result" contains above values. I have solved this issue using Lambda resolver.

```
var processItemsCallback = function(err, data) {
  if (err) { 
     //fail
  } else {
    var params = {};
    params.RequestItems = data.UnprocessedItems;
    if(Object.keys(params.RequestItems).length != 0) {
      db.batchWriteItem(params, processItemsCallback);
    }
  }
};

db.batchWriteItem(/*initial params*/, processItemsCallback);
```

I am curious to know if i can do something similar as lambda using **[DynamoDB Resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html)**

. Based on my analysis i think i cannot achieve something similar using **pipeline** too

Answer (score 0):

If you need to page, I suggest you handle that logic in the client by returning the next token or you implement this logic in a Lambda resolver.